# TGrid/TStringGrid multi cell selection / multi editing in delphi firemonkey (12)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tstringgrid, delphi-12-athens, tgrid

I switched from `VCL` to `Firemonkey` frame work and I noticed that `TGrid`/`TStringgrid` doesn't have multi select option in it. However, all I could find is this article(2013 release)
https://pictoselector.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/adding-multiselect-to-firemonkeys-tgrid/
but they seem to be outdated.
I want to achieve multi cell select + multi edit cell in `Firemonkey` framework without a 3rd party plugin.

Also, do I have to build my grid component from scratch or built it on to of the `TGrid` class or can I achieve it just from Evans?

Comment: Regarding the links you provided: The first one shows nothing related to a grid, so no comment. The second one is from an era before Firemonkey, and concerns the VCL TStringGrid. Whatever it's code does, is not applicable to the FMX grid component. In FMX you have to consider that each column is a separate object. Your question is too wide to fit SO.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg you are right sorry i guess i copy the wrong lik (sorry for my misstake) https://pictoselector.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/adding-multiselect-to-firemonkeys-tgrid/ this is the link that i was talking about (it's from 2013)